# Powershell display message both on console and in a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Not sure if this is a simple question or some code is required in order to achieve this, so here it goes.

I have a script which basically displays some text 1st on the PS console *and also* in a log file.

The code I have uses both the write-host and write-output, so my question is that if the 2 can be combined somehow?
I want only specific message to be logged, so doing a PS transcript will not work.

```
Write-host "Error: whatever message" 
Write-Output "Error: whatever message" | Out-File -Append $Log_file
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple answer is to use a Tee-Object.  In version 3 you should have access to the -Append parameter as well (but not in v2)

```
Write-Output "Error: whatever message" | Tee-Object -Append $Log_file
```

Comment: I think I like more the use of tee-object, so thanks a lot Knuckle-Dragger ;)

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can use `Add-Content` with `-Passthru`, and send on to `Write-Output` from there:

```
"Error: whatever message" | Add-Content $Log_file -PassThru | Write-Output
```